# How I read the data in mention format in python with for loop

Tags: python, loops, parsing, for-loop

How i read the following data in the the bellow format with for loop.

```
data = [
    [1,'Services',10],
    [2,'Cost Elements',20],
    [3, 'Rules',30],
    [4, 'Manpower', 40]
]
```

Expected output is::

```
p = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    ['services','Cost Elements','Rules','Manpower'],
    [10,20,30,40]
]
```

And:

```
{
        id:1,
        name:'services',
        value:10
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:'Cost Elements',
        value:20
    },
    {
        id:1,
        name:'Rules',
        value:30
    },
    {
        id:1,
        name:'Manpower',
        value:40
    }
```

Please help ..I am beginner in python so couldn't..

Comment: Can you put your attempt and the result you obtained in your question?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to transpose your list with `zip`.

```
>>> data = [
...     [1,'Services',10],
...     [2,'Cost Elements',20],
...     [3, 'Rules',30],
...     [4, 'Manpower', 40]
... ]
>>> 
>>> p = list(zip(*data))
>>> p
[(1, 2, 3, 4), ('Services', 'Cost Elements', 'Rules', 'Manpower'), (10, 20, 30, 40)]
```

... or with additional transformation of the inner tuples to lists:

```
>>> p = list(map(list, zip(*data)))
>>> p
[[1, 2, 3, 4], ['Services', 'Cost Elements', 'Rules', 'Manpower'], [10, 20, 30, 40]]
```

`zip` will group together all the elements at corresponding positions (e.g. `(sublist1[0], sublist2[0], ...)`) for any number of iterable arguments.

**~edit~**

If it must be a `for` loop, you could do something like this.

```
>>> result = [[] for _ in range(len(data[0]))]
>>> 
>>> for sublist in data:
...     for i, element in enumerate(sublist):
...         result[i].append(element)
... 
>>> result
[[1, 2, 3, 4], ['Services', 'Cost Elements', 'Rules', 'Manpower'], [10, 20, 30, 40]]
```

This is clunky and I don't recommend it.

Comment: Need output using for loop sir please

Comment: @pavan if you insist...

Comment: And guyz if i want like that:[
 {
  id:1,
  name:'services',
  value:10
 },
 {
  id:2,
  name:'Cost Elements',
  value:20
 },
 {
  id:1,
  name:'Rules',
  value:30
 },
 {
  id:1,
  name:'Manpower',
  value:40
 }
]

Comment: thank you sir ......please guide me above one .....today i am learning lots of about python i think

Comment: @pavan please don't ask follow up questions in comments. Don't be a [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258279/3620003).

Comment: so should i ask by editing main one....i am new on stack...!!!

Comment: @pavan you can ask a new question, but if you don't want to get it closed/downvoted read [ask] first.

Comment: can't ask new one so edit the main so, please guide me.

Comment: @pavan sorry, I'm already dizzy from loss of blood.

Comment: please, i am new and trying to learn python so .....

Comment: @pavan: the site is not a tutoring or mentoring site, and to use it in this way risks being blocked from asking, so please be careful.